# CSS Grid—wholenumber multiples for height of rows

Tags: css, css-grid

I am diving into CSS Grids and there is one thing I cannot get my Head around:

I want to have a Grid, with `n` columns and the height of each row should be a whole-number multiple of a given size `m`, depending on the cells' content.

Consider the following example, `X` stands for content

```
    1      2      3
+------+------+------+
|   X  |   X  |      |<-m
-   X  -      -      -  
|      |      |      |
+------+------+------+
```

So the content of cell 1/1 is slightly higher than `m`, so the whole row should be `2 * m` high, so forth for growing heights.

Right now I am here:

```
@mixin grid-container($cols: 6, $col-gap: 20px, $row-gap: 12px)
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat($cols, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 6*$row-gap;
  grid-column-gap: $col-gap;
  grid-row-gap: $row-gap;
}
```

But that does not respect the height of the content and it gets stacked. How can I fix that?

Comment: just wondering... to me this sounds like a strange requirement....if content is only slightly higher than `m` - why would you want to make the row height `2m`?  ... I'm don't think CSS can handle that

Comment: An example of your code and the preview of how is it getting stacked will help in understanding your question more!

Comment: The good old days of tables are back.

Answer (score 0):

The content will automatically push the height of row and hence no need of `grid-auto-rows`. Similar behavior can be achieved by `min-height` on columns.

Followin example shows that. It used css variables and calc about which you can read here

- https://time2hack.com/2018/04/postcss-cssnext-turbocharge-css-development/
- https://time2hack.com/2018/03/postcss-css-preprocessor-in-javascript/

[image]

```css
:root {
    --row-gap: 12px;
    --col-gap: 20px;
    --col-count: 6;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--col-count), 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: var(--col-gap);
  grid-row-gap: var(--row-gap);
}
.col {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: calc(var(--col-count) * var(--row-gap))
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">

    <div class="col">A<br/>B<br/>A<br/>B<br/>A<br/>B</div>
    <div class="col">C</div>
    <div class="col">D</div>
    <div class="col">E</div>
    <div class="col">F</div>
    <div class="col">-</div>

    <div class="col">A<br/>B</div>
    <div class="col">C</div>
    <div class="col">D</div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col">T<br/>D</div>

</div>
```